# How to use a custom user control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I was searching for a 'waiting' animation for silverlight after I realized that GIF animations doesn't work in Silverlight. I found an excellent animation [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/137935/355675.aspx). How can I use this in my application. Do I need to create any custom controls. I just want to place this over my dataview until the items gets populated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this implementation in [Coproject](http://baud.cz/blog/coproject-ria-caliburnmicro-demo-part-10) on codeplex.

If you're using mvvm, you can wrap operations in a using.  The BusyWatcher gets injected into the ViewModel using MEF.

```
 [Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
        public IBusyWatcher Busy { get; set; }
```

then:

```
 using (Busy.GetTicket())
 {
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `UserControl` call it something sensible like `WaitAnim1`.

The sample you point to overuses Grids.  The outer grid represent in your case the UserControl. Do the following to make your usercontrol from that original code:-

- copy the `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` namespace to your UserControl element.
- copy the whole `Grid.Resources` to **directly** under the `<UserControl>` tag and rename `Grid.Resources` to `UserControl.Resources`
- copy whole `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >` element from the source code and replace the one in your usercontrol with it.

You now have a usercontrol that when displayed will show the animation.